# Bitmap data saved at wrong coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following code:

```
var imageScreenshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(675, 540);

    imageScreenshot.draw( stage, null, null, "normal", new Rectangle(297, 163, 675, 540),true);

    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
    var jpgBytes:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(imageScreenshot);

    var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();


fileRef.save(jpgBytes, "output.jpg");
```

I want a particular area to be 'screenshotted' and output as a .jpeg file, so I drew a rectangle on the stage that covered the area I want to screenshot, took the x, y, width and height values and typed them into the above code and then removed the rectangle but the output has a lot of empty space to the top and the left and I want to get rid of this, but reducing the size of the `BitmapData` ends up cutting part of the stage off that I want to screenshot.

I'm not quite sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should crop the bitmap not by using `clipRect` but by using a temporary bitmap and `copyPixels()` the desired region.

```
var imageScreenshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(675, 540);
var tempBD:BitmapData=new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.staheHeight);
tempBD.draw( stage, null, null, "normal", null,true);
imageScreenshot.copyPixels(tempBD,new Rectangle(297, 163, 675, 540),new Point(0,0));
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
var jpgBytes:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(imageScreenshot);
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.save(jpgBytes, "output.jpg");
```

If this still produces empty space or a wrong part of stage, check for the actual coordinates.